# Go: deploy on Heroku

Tags: heroku, go

With help of [the article](http://www.zhubert.com/blog/2014/03/08/deploying-golang-to-heroku/) I'm trying to deploy Go-lang app to heroku. The problem is I get an error while deploying

```
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Go app detected
-----> Installing go1.4... done

       Tired of waiting for bzr and hg?
       Try github.com/kr/godep for faster deploys.

       Installing Virtualenv... done
       Installing Mercurial... done
       Installing Bazaar... done
-----> Running: go get -tags heroku ./...
go install: no install location for directory /tmp/build_2c4fa2d4b9d0408123831030713fa930/.heroku/g/src outside GOPATH

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app
```

What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: `.godir` is deprecated in favor of godep, you may get better results using that. See official directions at http://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it you should get [Godep](https://github.com/tools/godep)

```
go get github.com/kr/godep
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

after that in project directory

```
godep save
```

more information in the [artice](http://www.goinggo.net/2013/10/manage-dependencies-with-godep.html)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku now [officially supports](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/7/7/go_support_now_official_on_heroku) Go and has a [Getting Started guide](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/7/7/go_support_now_official_on_heroku) and other [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/go).